# Oracle 11g Package Overloads Across Schemas

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a package (with a public synonym) in "schema1" that is called by many packages in "schema2". The signature of a function in the "schema1" package changed, which broke all the code calling that function from "schema2".

I don't have any way to change "schema1" so I thought I could recreate that package in "schema2" with the same spec as the matching package in "schema1" with the addition of an overload for the broken function. The package body just passes the parameters to "schema1.package1", so future changes to the logic within the existing functions would not require changes to the anything in "schema2".

This works great, until the evil developers controlling "schema1" add a new function or procedure to package1. When this is done, code in "schema2" can't see the new functions or procedures.

For example:

```
-- Package in schema1, shown here for reference.
create or replace package schema1.package1 as
  function function1(num1 in number, date1 in date) return number;
end package1;

-- Package in scheam2.
create or replace package schema2.package1 as
  function function1(num1 in number) return number;
end package1;

-- Package body in scheam2.
create or replace package body schema2.package1 as
  function function1(num1 in number) return number as begin
    return schema1.package1.function1(num1,sysdate);
  end;
end package1;
```

When I call the following from "schema2", it works fine:

```
select package1.function1(123) from dual;
```

When I call the following from "schema2", it fails:

```
select package1.function1(123, sysdate) from dual;

ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'function1'
```

So, it's clearly not looking past the local package to the public synonym for the second call, which is probably by design but, I really would like to see if I can get this to work.

I know I can just add both to the package in "schema2" like this:

```
create or replace package schema2.package1 as
  function function1(num1 in number) return number;
  function function1(num1 in number, date1 in date) return number;
end package1;

create or replace package body schema2.package1 as
  function function1(num1 in number) return number as begin
    return schema1.package1.function1(num1, sysdate);
  end;
  function function1(num1 in number, date1 in date) return number as begin
    return schema1.package1.function1(num1, date1);
  end;
end package1;
```

But this isn't going to work for me because every time another function or procedure is added to the package in "schema1", I would need to update the package in "schema2" so the developers using "schema2" have access to it (without directly referencing it, which is unfortunately not an option).

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use the package in Schema 2 to buffer changes to method signatures in Schema 1, you'd have to update it whenever a new method was added that you want users to be able to call.  Taking a step back, though, if you're adding new parameters to methods in the Schema 1 package that have sensible defaults, why not ask the developers to add them as optional parameters?  That way, you don't need to maintain your own package and your code doesn't break when new optional parameters get added?

Comment: My team has a very low priority, we tried to ask them to create optional parameters or overloads to maintain backwards compatibility and they basically said no. That would have been the ideal solution. Since we couldn't get them to change, I was hoping to come up with an alternative solution without having to duplicate everything in the package, but just the things that changed. It seems like that's not going to be possible. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to reference package1.newfunction in schema1 from schema2 just by prefixing the schema reference: schema1.package1.newfunction or by creating a local synonym: `CREATE SYNONYM S1_PACKAGE1 FOR SCHEMA1.PACKAGE1;`

This way your local wrapper package can hide the signature changes allowing current code to continue to work, but new code that wants or needs to take advantage of the new functionality in SCHEMA1.PACKAGE1 still can by using an alternate reference.

However, you really should get on the case of SCHEMA1's devs since package specs represent a contract that they've broken by altering the signatures in a non backwards compatible way.

Comment: This is the second time the "schema1" developers have done this to us in the past 3 years or so. No matter what we say, they won't change. Accessing the package by prefixing the schema name in the future would be a hard sell to my team, and wouldn't address all the code already in place with the current non-prefixed calls without recreating all the current ones that don't need to be recreated. I believe the correct answer to my question is "it can't be done yet".

Comment: I was suggesting that for current code you use your wrapper package to replicate the lost functionality, for new code using new schema1 functionality you can use a locally defined synonym.  Then in the future if schema1 again changes there specs in a way that breaks your code, you can update your local package to restore functionality, repoint your local synonym to your local package, and create yet another local synonym to point back to schema1's package in order to pick up the new functionality.